# React higher-order components: making assumptions about wrapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a function to decorate a React component class with behavior for keyboard-navigating through a list of items, like so:

```
function MakeNavigable(ListComponent) {
  class NavigableComponent extends React.component {
    handleListKeydown(event) {
      const listLength = this.refs.list.getListLength();
      if (event.keyCode === 40 && this.state.focusedRow < listLength - 1) {
        // handle down arrow
        this.setState({ focusedRow: this.state.focusedRow + 1 });
      }
      // handle other keys here...
    },

    render() {
      return (
        <ListComponent onListKeydown={this.handleListKeydown} ref="list" />
      );
    },
  }

 return NavigableComponent;
}
```

Notice that I'm calling a method on the wrapped component, `getListLength()`, meaning I have to assume that `ListComponent` exposes such a method.

What's the best way to ensure that a function like this only accepts component classes to wrap that have the required instance properties or methods? Is it even a valid use of a higher-order component to depend on getting information from the wrapped component like this? If not, what is the alternative? Navigation behavior could be provided by a mixin instead, but according to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins):

> Unfortunately ES6 launched without any mixin support. Therefore, there is no support for mixins when you use React with ES6 classes. Instead, we're working on making it easier to support such use cases without resorting to mixins.

Comment: have you tried using decorators? there isn't a lot out there, but there are some repos that have good examples, here's one, mind you its bare: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-decorators

Comment: Well yes, the higher-order-component creator above could be applied with a decorator. The question is, what are best practices for higher-order components that need information from the decorated class?

Comment: @dysfunction if you're also passing the list into the `ListComponent` then you would have access as a prop as well?

Comment: basically its not possible to require refs, because they don't exist until render has been completed. Since they don't always exist, its bad to depend on them. If you add more info we can find a better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to ensure that a function like this only accepts component classes to wrap that have the required instance properties or methods?

**You cannot ensure that a higher-order-component will only take a component that has a property/function.**

> Is it even a valid use of a higher-order component to depend on getting information from the wrapped component like this?

**No, its not really a valid use.**

> If not, what is the alternative?

**You should refactor the `getList` code into the higher order component, then you won't need to require it exists on the child.**